# Duda con prueba junit 5

Tags: java, testing, junit-5

Estoy utilizando junit 5 para realizar pruebas unitarias. Es la primera vez que me pongo a realizar este tipo de pruebas. Tengo que testear sobre una clase, y en jacoco me sale el mensaje que me falta cubrir una parte de una función. El tema es que no tengo idea de cómo cubrir el código faltante que me tira jacoco:

Función

```
public void processMovimientos(Lote lote, InputStream inputStream, ArchivoMovimientosCabecera cabecera)
            throws ArchivoInvalidoException {
        AtomicReference<Empresa> empresa = new AtomicReference<>();
        try {
            movimientoArchivoService.parseMovimientos(empresa, lote, inputStream, cabecera);
            loteValidationService.validateLote(lote, empresa.get(), cabecera);
        } catch (ArchivoInvalidoException e) {
            estadoLoteService.updateEstado(lote, EstadosLote.RECHAZADO);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (empresa.get() != null) {
                lote.setEmpresa(empresa.get());
                loteDao.updateEmpresa(lote);
            }
        }
    }
```

En esta función me tira casi todo en rojo, y no sé qué poner para que me lo tome como testeado.
Me marca en rojo el objeto empresa, el try, el catch y el finally.

Comment: por lo que vemos, el error se debe a que no tienes ningun codigo de la prueba unitaria, sin codigo de pruebas el coverage siempre va a ser 0%

Comment: El tema es que no sé como testear eso. Justamente lo que pido es un ejemplo de como testearlo de una forma que me cubra todo. Lo que hice fue hacer unos mocks y un verify a la función, ya que es un void, no devuelve nada.

Comment: y por que no los pusiste en la pregunta para tener un [mcve]?